# Trouble configuring database access to MySQL from Zend and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework, connection

I don't understand why this isn't working.

I want to access to my database. My application.ini looks like this:

```
resources.db.adapter  = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "127.0.0.1"
resources.db.params.dbname = "testdb"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

In my bootstrap.php I inserted the posting of one of the other users in related postings:

```
protected function _initRegistry(){

$this->bootstrap('db');
$db = $this->getResource('db');   
$db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);   
Zend_Registry::set('db', $db);
}
```

In my IndexController inside the indexAction I tried to initialize my DB Model

```
$books = new Bibliothek();
/*$bookList*/
$this->view->bibliothek=$books->fetchAll();
```

The whole website is now blank, without the code in indexAction I only get the menus and so on.

Last year I tried a bit with an older Zend Version (now I´m using 1.11) I had no problem in getting my data from the database.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your site goes blank when there are errors and the application can't display them, add this line to your .htaccess file to enable errors to display: `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development`. I suspect your issue is a failure to connect to db or incorrectly using the adapter in your model.

Comment: thank you that helped! I found the error!

Comment: @pia-sophie then add an answer yourself and mark it as correct. It may help someone

Answer (score 0):

as @RockyFord said:

if your Zend Application is just rendering a blank page, there is probably an error. Errors aren't shown in production envrionments so they dont leak information about the application.
If the APPLICATION_ENV is "development" the Zend Application will show errors. Insert the following line into /public/.htaccess

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```